# Why do I keep getting similar errors while trying to run processing using Jython in Eclipse?

Tags: java, python, processing, jython

I have been trying to run a couple of processing (java based) sketches using Jython. However, in both cases I am getting similar errors which I can not resolve.
Here is my first piece of very basic code:

```
from processing.core import PApplet

class HelloProcessing(PApplet):
def setup(self):
    global p
    p = self
    p.size(350, 350)

def draw(self):
    p.fill(p.random(255))
    p.rect(150, 150, 50, 50)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pawt
    pawt.test(HelloProcessing())
```

I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nimanamjouyan/workspace/LearningPyDev/src/helloProcessing.py", line 15, in <module>
    pawt.test(HelloProcessing())
  File "/home/nimanamjouyan/jython-installer-2.7.0/Lib/pawt/__init__.py", line 9, in test
    f.add('Center', panel)
TypeError: add(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String, java.awt.Component
```

The other piece of code I am trying to run is this:

```
from javax.swing import JFrame
from processing.core import PApplet
from random import uniform

winWidth=600
winHeight=500
numBoxes = 1000
boxes = []

class RandBoxes (PApplet):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def setup(self):
        self.size(winWidth, winHeight, self.JAVA2D)
        while len(boxes)<numBoxes:
            boxes.append(Box(self,     uniform(0,winWidth),uniform(0,winHeight)))
        print "number of boxes = %d" % len(boxes)
    # rqd due to PApplet's using frameRate and frameRate(n) etc.
    def getField(self, name):
        #return self.class.superclass.getDeclaredField(name).get(self)
        return self.PApplet.getDeclaredField(name).get(self)

    def draw(self):
        self.background(128)
        for b in boxes:
            b.step()
        if self.frameCount % 10 == 0:
            print "frameRate=%f frameCount=%i" % (self.getField('frameRate'), self.frameCount)

class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, p, x, y):
        self.p = p
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.c = p.color(255,255,0)
    def step(self):
        self.x = max(min(self.x+uniform(-1,1),winWidth),0)
        self.y = max(min(self.y+uniform(-1,1),winHeight),0)
        self.paint()
    def paint(self):
        self.p.noStroke()
        self.p.fill(self.c)
        self.p.rect(self.x-2,self.y-2,5,5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame = JFrame(title="Processing",resizable =  0,defaultCloseOperation=JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    panel = RandBoxes()
    frame.add(panel)
    panel.init()
    while panel.defaultSize and not panel.finished:
    pass
    frame.pack()
    frame.visible = 1
```

The error I am getting this time is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nimanamjouyan/workspace/LearningPyDev/src/RandBoxesTest.py", line 54, in <module>
    frame.add(panel)
TypeError: add(): 1st arg can't be coerced to java.awt.PopupMenu, java.awt.Component
```

These two errors seem to be very similar. What am I doing wrong here? is java.awt incompatible with the class that I am parsing to? How can I fix this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi there,

I actually found a solution which makes the program work, but it does not address the problem. The "core.jar" file which I was using was from Processing 3.2.3. I changed it with the "core.jar" from Processing 1.5.1 and 2.2.1 and for both of them I no longer got the error and the program worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is a result of `PApplet` no longer extending `Applet` and no longer being directly embedded in a `JFrame` as of Processing 3. For more info, see [this page](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0).

Presumably the library you're using relies on `PApplet` extending `Applet`, so it won't work with Processing 3. That's why your solution of going back to an older version of Processing works.

You'd have to check your library's documentation to see if there's a way to make it work with Processing 3. Otherwise you're stuck using the older versions of Processing for now.